# Sublime - How to trigger snippet on arrow '>>'

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I want to create a `sublime snippet` for `ES6 lambda`
 but the snippet does not trigger on arrow **'>>'**. How can I make this work?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snippet has to be valid XML.

Therefore, your `<tabTrigger>` should look like this: `<tabTrigger>&gt;&gt;</tabTrigger>`

`&gt;` is a character entity that respresents the `>` character.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i've tried &gt;&gt; before, it still not working

Comment: works for me on ST3 build 3107. it's a tab trigger, so you need to type `>>` in a JavaScript file and then press the `tab` key on your keyboard

Comment: well, I'm using ST2, maybe this feature only works on ST3

Comment: You probably have to remove the `>` character from your `word_separators` setting so you can trigger the snippet.